# bind_param error where correct number of params are supplied?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The very simple script below is designed to return a forename and a surname based on a GET variable.

Every time the script is run this error is displayed:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in mypath/names.php on line 10

I have checked the SQL query and it works perfectly fine in SQLyog. I am also calling the file with the get variable: names.php?surname=jo

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
require_once('connection.php');

$db = DB::connect();
$db->select_db("mydb");
$sql = "SELECT forename,surname FROM `people` WHERE `surname` LIKE '?%' LIMIT 1";

if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['surname']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($forename, $surname);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: what happens if you hard code $_GET['surname'] ? $stmt->bind_param("s", "hello");

Comment: @mazraara Just tried this and it didn't work :[

Comment: what happens if you change, $sql = "SELECT forename,surname FROM `people` WHERE `surname` LIKE '?%' LIMIT 1"; IN TO ----> $sql = "SELECT forename,surname FROM `people` WHERE `surname` =? LIMIT 1";

Comment: @mazraara Still doesn't work! I think PHP is trolling

Comment: The answer posted by Pierre should work. give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
$sql = "SELECT forename,surname FROM `people` WHERE `surname` LIKE ? LIMIT 1";
```

with

```
$surname=$_GET['surname']."%";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $surname);
```